# Which target is needed to mock modules used inside a Class with unittest.mock?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I need to create a module-scoped fixture where I mock `module_a` and `module_c` used inside `module_b.Module_B_Class()`.  I cannot use mock.patch annotation because it provides a function-scoped mock and I also need to assert that, when invoking `Module_B_Class` a specific function is invoked on `module_a` and another function is invoked on `module_c`. So I used pytest-cases unpack_into feature and wrote the following fixture:

```
@pytest_cases.fixture_plus(scope="module", unpack_into="mocked_module_a,mocked_module_b")
def my_fixture():
     with mock.patch('my_top_module.my_sub_module.module_b.module_a') as module_a_mock:
          with mock.patch('my_top_module.my_sub_module.module_b.module_c') as module_c_mock:
          module_a_mock.my_func = MagicMock(return_value='Hello world')
          module_c_mock.my_func_2 = MagicMock(return_value='Good morning')
```

However, when I run the following:

```
def test_my_class(mocked_module_a, mocked_module_b):
    my_class = Module_B_Class()
    my_class.run()
    mocked_module_a.assert_called_once()
    mocked_module_b.assert_called_once()
```

which is defined like so

```
from my_top_module.my_sub_module import module_a
class Module_B_Class():
      def run(self):
          module_a.my_func()
          module_c.my_func2()
```

the function which is invoked is the original one and not the replaced one. Is the target I am patching the wrong one?

Comment: Are both `module_a` and `module_b` located under `my_top_module.my_sub_module`?

Comment: correct, they are

Comment: Ah, you seem to be missing the `yield` in your fixture (and the `self` parameter in `run`, but that is probably a typo). Other than that, it looks ok to me.

Comment: Can you point me towards the docs of how fixtures are supposed to be using yield ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixtures are described in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html). The basic principle is that the code before the `yield` is executed before the test (or depending on the scope, before the first test, each module, or each test class), and the code after the `yield` is executed after the test (or the last test, the module, or class):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    do_setup()
    yield 
    do_teardown()
```

You can also return a value using `yield`, of course.

For a context manager that means, you have to yield before going out of scope:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def my_fixture():
     with mock.patch('my_top_module.my_sub_module.module_b.module_a') as module_a_mock:
          module_a_mock.my_func = MagicMock(return_value='Hello world')
          yield module_a_mock
```

You can now access the mock via the fixture name in your test, if you need to. In this case, the code returns after the `yield` only after the tests in the current module are executed, so at that point the patch is reverted.

If you don't do the `yield` in this case, you get out of scope immediately on fixture execution, meaning that the patch is reverted before you get to the test.

*UPDATE*:

Here is the version for the updated question which uses `pytest_cases`:

```py
@pytest_cases.fixture_plus(scope="module",
                           unpack_into="mocked_module_a,mocked_module_c")
def my_fixture():
    with mock.patch(
            'my_top_module.my_sub_module.module_b.module_a') as module_a_mock:
        with mock.patch(
                'my_top_module.my_sub_module.module_b.module_c') as module_c_mock:
            module_a_mock.my_func = mock.MagicMock(return_value='Hello world')
            module_c_mock.my_func2 = mock.MagicMock(return_value='Good  morning')
            yield (module_a_mock, module_c_mock)


def test_my_class(mocked_module_a, mocked_module_c):
    my_class = Module_B_Class()
    my_class.run()
    mocked_module_a.my_func.assert_called_once()
    mocked_module_c.my_func2.assert_called_once()
```

Note: I have renamed `mocked_module_b` to `mocked_module_c` to avoid confusion. Also `assert_called_once` had been called on the module instead of the function.

Comment: Brilliant. It makes lot of sense, the only problem I have is that in reality I have two mocks and I am using pytest-cases with fixture_plus to unpack them, but using generators and unpacking them yields an error:        (the tuple to unpack)
        source_fixture_value = kwargs.pop(source_f_name)
        # unpack: get the item at the right position.
>       return source_fixture_value[_value_idx]
E       TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Now it should all makes much more sense, I have updated the question to be much more precise and clear

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Didn't know `pytest_cases` - very convenient!

Comment: Let me try. I think there is a problem with the generators and pytest-cases